# Why is my ng-click event firing twice?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm developing a cordova/ionic app, and currently using the Android Emulator on my laptop to test it. I have a `ng-click` event that's firing twice. When I view the call stack for the first execution, this is what I see:

```
CreateAdController.$scope.save in create-ad-ctrl.js, line 96    JavaScript
fn in eval code.js, line 3002   JavaScript
<anonymous function> in ionic.bundle.js, line 62386 JavaScript
Scope.$eval in ionic.bundle.js, line 29158  JavaScript
Scope.$apply in ionic.bundle.js, line 29257 JavaScript
<anonymous function> in ionic.bundle.js, line 62385 JavaScript
eventHandler in ionic.bundle.js, line 16583 JavaScript
triggerMouseEvent in ionic.bundle.js, line 2948 JavaScript
tapClick in ionic.bundle.js, line 2937  JavaScript
tapTouchEnd in ionic.bundle.js, line 3064   JavaScript
```

The second execution has a *slightly* different call stack:

```
CreateAdController.$scope.save in create-ad-ctrl.js, line 96    JavaScript
fn in eval code.js, line 3002   JavaScript
<anonymous function> in ionic.bundle.js, line 62386 JavaScript
Scope.$eval in ionic.bundle.js, line 29158  JavaScript
Scope.$apply in ionic.bundle.js, line 29257 JavaScript
<anonymous function> in ionic.bundle.js, line 62385 JavaScript
eventHandler in ionic.bundle.js, line 16583 JavaScript
triggerMouseEvent in ionic.bundle.js, line 2948 JavaScript
tapClick in ionic.bundle.js, line 2937  JavaScript
tapMouseUp in ionic.bundle.js, line 3013    JavaScript
```

The most notable difference here is the last line (or the first line of execution), specifically

```
tapTouchEnd in ionic.bundle.js, line 3064   JavaScript
```

and

```
tapMouseUp in ionic.bundle.js, line 3013    JavaScript
```

The first is a `tapTouchEnd` event, the second is `tapMouseUp`.

Is there a way for me to prevent this firing twice? Is this because I'm testing on my laptop, and it's firing the `tapMouseUp` event naturally because that's actually happening?

For the record I've seen cases before of events firing twice because a controller would be referenced twice. I can confirm that this is not the case in this instance. I can also confirm that `ionic.bundle.js` is referenced only once.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using alert() anywhere in your codebase?  Take a look at [this bug](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-bundle-js-causes-ng-click-event-to-fire-multiple-times/32008)

You can replace alert with cordovaDialog

Comment: No, I'm not using any alert() dialogs. Interesting bug though!